# jquery submit select box

Tags: jquery, forms, listbox, submit

I have a form. It consists of text area and select box.
I want to submit it to server side.
The following is front-end code. 
The back-end code has only one sentence: "print_r ($_POST);". It prints out the data users filled and selected. 
The problem is I can see the data users filled But I cannot see the data in select box.
For example, I want to see:

```
Array ( [name] => hello [email] => ***@hotmail.com [list] => NYC)
```

But it only shows:

```
Array ( [name] => hello [email] => ***@hotmail.com)
```

That said, it cannot show the data in selected box.

```
<form name="contact", action="ajax.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name" id="name_label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />

      <label for="email" id="email_label">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" size="30" value="" class="text-input" />

      <select id="list" >
      <option></option>
      <option value="NYC">NYC</option>
      <option value="USA">USA</option>
      </select>

    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
      // validate and process form here
    $('.error').hide();
      var name = $("input#name").val();
      var email = $("input#email").val();
      var list = $("select#list").val();

      var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&list=' + list;
      alert(dataString); 
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: dataString,
       url : "ajax.php",
     });   
   });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: If your code does not appear in the preview, use the code formatting.

Comment: you should set th e name attr of the select tag

Comment: @JoeTuskan: The OP is sending the data via XHR.

Comment: wouldn't he need a preventdefault call?

Comment: @JoeTuskan: Yes, I would say so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any errors with your code, however, creating the list of params yourself is redundant.

You could simply serialise that form with `$('form[name="contact"]').serialize()`.

However, if you are submitting this form in addition to the XHR, you need to give the `select` element a `name` attribute.

Also, if you intended to submit via XHR *and* normal submission, I would prevent the default event for submit and call `submit()` in the success of your XHR. Otherwise, the request may not finish.

Comment: I tried to add name attribute called location.                                     var list = $("select#list").attr("location");  I used alert(dataString) to show whether I can get correct data. It is strange that it shows "list=undefined".

Comment: Could you please explain more on prevent default event?